# How do I do a reverse DNS lookup from IP address to domain name?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, nslookup

I want to know the source of a server IP address domain name. For example, as shown in the picture, the domain name `meping.igamecj.com` replies with 20 addresses, so my main question is how do I use any of these 20 addresses to trace back to that Domain name?

[image: https://pasteboard.co/IXAaa5l.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple posibilities to look up the name of an ipadress (depending on os and installd software ofcourse):
`dig -x 192.0.2.4`
`nslookup 192.0.2.4`
`host 192.0.2.4`

Comment: I tried both but they dont work for me.

Comment: What os? Or perhaps there is no reverse PTR-record defined for the ipadresses

Comment: Windows 10 64bit. Well in some applications (like Wireshark) there's a way to sniff DNS queries which leak Domain names after being requested for IP address. Unfortunately i cant use wireshark due to driver limitations. so i just need an easy alternative way to fetch that kind of information. How?

Comment: On Windows: `nslookup`, but your ipadresses have no PTR set so you cant query them...

Comment: It is absolutely not guaranteed that an IP address has a PTR record and hence that any of the commands above will give anything back.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, you can't, at least not in a definitive automated way.
But see here a list of possible partial solutions.

### 1) `PTR` records

In theory, as shown in another reply, you can ask for `PTR` records, that maps an IP address back to a name.
However:

- they are not mandatory to exist for any given IP address
- and most of the time they don't exist in fact (except for email servers typically)
- as they do not provide any value and are "complicated" to setup straight (because the delegation is from another part of the DNS tree, called the reverse, and that comes from the RIRs and not the domain registries, and people have trouble to access it)
- and even if the record exists, there is no guarantee that it matches the forward (from IP to name) mapping, on purpose or not

### 2) IP blocks registrations at RIRs

Depending on why you need to do all that, there is a possible hint through another way.

IP blocks are reserved at RIRs, and RIRs provide whois access (or RDAP) for public data that shows who owns which block.

So with a good whois client, or using a web interface (https://stat.ripe.net/ is a very good one, done by one of the RIRs), by doing `whois 20.37.82.16` you should be able to get back:

```
NetRange:       20.33.0.0 - 20.128.255.255
CIDR:           20.33.0.0/16, 20.128.0.0/16, 20.64.0.0/10, 20.48.0.0/12, 20.40.0.0/13, 20.34.0.0/15, 20.36.0.0/14
NetName:        MSFT
NetHandle:      NET-20-33-0-0-1
Parent:         NET20 (NET-20-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:
Organization:   Microsoft Corporation (MSFT)
RegDate:        2017-10-18
Updated:        2017-10-18
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/20.33.0.0
```

In that specific case that does not help you a lot, as you see Microsoft here. Further in the output you can see email addresses: in other cases the email addresses (or company name, etc.) could have had something related to the name at the beginning which as said above, would have been an hint (but that remains an heuristic not a full proof).

### 3) Routing

Sometimes looking at the routing to that IP address can reveal useful data. Not really in this case, as you kind of get the same leads as from the previous point, but could be useful in other cases:

```
tcptraceroute 20.37.82.16 443

[..]

 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  100.65.13.241  54.799 ms  53.379 ms  53.558 ms
 8  52.93.28.149  54.478 ms  54.256 ms  54.823 ms
 9  100.100.4.8  54.509 ms  54.943 ms  62.507 ms
10  99.82.178.161  55.087 ms  55.081 ms  54.607 ms
11  ae26-0.icr01.bl20.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.40.63)  56.932 ms  56.139 ms  55.554 ms
12  be-140-0.ibr03.bl20.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.21.223)  244.656 ms  243.479 ms  244.786 ms
13  be-8-0.ibr01.nyc30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.19.195)  243.750 ms  243.729 ms  243.429 ms
14  be-10-0.ibr01.lon22.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.18.153)  243.615 ms  244.268 ms  245.087 ms
15  be-5-0.ibr01.par30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.17.76)  243.972 ms  243.778 ms  243.277 ms
16  be-3-0.ibr01.mrs20.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.7.46)  243.608 ms * 243.814 ms
17  be-2-0.ibr01.auh20.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.16.245)  244.131 ms  243.815 ms  243.547 ms
18  ae100-0.icr01.auh20.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.20.222)  243.083 ms  243.291 ms  243.295 ms
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
```

Showing it goes into "msn.net" territory you can see it is related to Microsoft in some way.

(`tcptraceroute` on some well known port like `443` is prefered over `traceroute` for any serious troubleshooting)

### 4) "Reverse" historical Databases

There are online databases that track, through time, the mapping between names and IP addresses. Which means, once recorded, you can obviously search in the opposite direction. This is however all proprietary, each provider does that alone, and under its own specific agreements, for a fee or not, etc.

### 5) Search Engines

As funny as it looks, you can use a search engine on that specific IP address and hope it was used somewhere at some point.
You might also get a lot of links towards services described in point 4 above.

For example at
https://igamecj.com.ipaddress.com/meping.igamecj.com
which shows this text:

```
What IP addresses does meping.igamecj.com resolve to?
meping.igamecj.com resolves to the following 20 IPv4 addresses:

    20.37.82.4
    20.37.82.5
    20.37.82.6
    20.37.82.7
    20.37.82.8
    20.37.82.9
    20.37.82.10
    20.37.82.11
    20.37.82.12
    20.37.82.13
    20.37.82.14
    20.37.82.15
    20.37.82.16
    20.37.82.17
    20.37.82.18
    20.37.82.19
    20.37.82.20
    20.37.82.21
    20.37.82.22
    20.37.82.23

In what country are meping.igamecj.com servers located in?
meping.igamecj.com has servers located in the United Arab Emirates.
```